# How to transfer movie data from PC to an Android smart phone

Tags: video, android, data-transfer

I have made a movie file (wmv) editing some raw video data by Windows Movie Maker.
Now the data is stored in my PC, and I want to transfer to my Android smartphone.

First I tried to download it, but it didn't work. I uploaded the video onto my Google drive, and then accessed the video file by my smartphone and tapped "download" button. At first it seemed to successfully download, but I couldn't open the downloaded file.

Next I tried to transfer the data via USB cable. But the problem is that I couldn't find the way to change the smartphone's default setting to allow my PC to transfer the data.

Now it feels like I'm stuck.

Could anyone tell me any hint for a solution to this problem?

Comment: What does your PC do when you plug the USB cable with the phone?
Did you instruct it to "do nothing" the first time you connected it?
Does the phone show up in Explorer?
What Windows and Android versions do you have?

Comment: You may have to reselect AutoPlay options https://www.groovypost.com/howto/disable-manage-autoplay-external-devices-windows-10/ or https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c18d15f6-25fa-466e-84bc-de76536ef8b0/how-to-change-default-action-when-a-device-is-connected-to-windows-8?forum=w8itprogeneral

Comment: It's Windows 10 and Android version 7.0. I don't think I gave any particular instruction to the devices the first time I connected them. Yes, it shows up in Explorer, but it says something like "it's empty"

Comment: A message box should show up in your cell phone asking if you allow access

Comment: But in reality it's not showing up, at least not on my smartphone...

Comment: When you plug the phone via USB, try swiping down from the top of the screen, and looking for a notification item regarding the USB connection.